How to convert model edges into curves?


How to convert model edges into curves? Can it be implemented in the form of geometric nodes?Need 2D contour。
Source file download

Because the model is quite complex, I have two ideas now,
1: It can be achieved through projection mapping
2: After unfolding the UV according to the view, use AI to stroke and then convert it

You want only the contours, right? And it's 2d?

That's right 2d

Thank you for your answer. Convert it to an editable plane or grid, which is the current perspective, and convert it to a 2D editable plane or grid

Thank you ，Is there a way to directly convert the outer contour into a mesh?

Thank you. This model is too complex and cannot be converted from projection cutting. Can we really only use dynamic drawing. thank you

I'm almost finishing some idea, I think it will work.

Found a (maybe not good) solution that creates the mesh contour (which you can convert to curve if you like).
It works like this:

Resamples the whole geometry in small distances (because some edges on the borders are very long and don't have vertices in the middle)
For each point in the resampled geometry, creates a circle of raycasts around it pointing down
If any of these raycasts don't hit the original geometry, it means it's a border point, keep it. (If all hit, point is inside)
After separating all border points, several islands appear made of connected edges
Get the longest island
Get the extremities of the longest island
Gets the nearest points from the remaining islands
Creates a line connecting the longest island with the nearest points in other islands
Finally closes the remaining gap (sometimes it doesn't exist, sometimes it does, depends on the number of islands)

General nodes

Contour islands by raycasting

"Ray Positions" is a circle of positions around the position of the target point
"Rays down" performs a raycast for each of the circle positions
"Any Not Hit" performs boolean operations, if any ray didn't hit, it's a border point
You can see these groups in detail in the uploaded file (don't want to make this answer too big)


Separating longest island
Where "Island Edge Length" sums the length of all edges of each island (I didn't do it with a curve because some islands had a single point, and the conversion of single points to curve removes them)

Joining islands
Where "Start e End" get the start and end vertice positions of the island

Close ends

File
This file has also another attempt that tries to make a full circle around and raycast this circle inwards. But it's hard to avoid edges crossing inside the wake if the wake has tips pointing outward
Important: Some "snap distance" settings may create weird contours. I could not avoid that, so you need to experiment for the ideal number (it's not hard to find a good number, if it's small enough, there are more good numbers than bad numbers)


Thank you for your answer. I have used it and adjusted some values to achieve the desired effect. Thank you.

Thank you for your answer ，Contour islands by raycasting Very useful.If I want a 3D version, may I ask where I can make modifications to make it easier to come up with another version?

I don't think this method can be extended to 3d. It's a whole new story.

@ASD1ASD21, I had an idea for 3d, uses raycast, but must change a lot. (Each point raycasts "out" in all directions. All hits mean inside (may fail in sharp corners and need more directions)
