How to convert the current perspective into a planar mesh?

How to convert the current perspective into a planar mesh?

As long as there is a flat grid, it can be used for silhouette, which converts the content seen from the current perspective into a flat grid or curve.

UV can be projected according to the current perspective and then converted into a grid, that's how I think.

Is there a way to directly convert the outer contour into a mesh?

You can add Grease Pencil Line Art:

It has silhouette mode. As you can see it's a bit chaotic in 3d space, but you can convert it to mesh and scale to 0 in Z axis using a custom Transform Orientation made from the camera. It's not perfect, there might be some tiny errors that need correcting and you need to fill the shapes, but it works:


Thank you for your answer. I have tried this method and the answer on Monkey Head is correct. However, I have a more complex model and I don't know why it is wrong. Can you help me look at the new model again?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/328168/how-to-convert-model-edges-into-curves

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AwARJ6T-X6HOyKxUZt5tzRkfeZSMM0aT/view
